# Talend big tables copy from one db to another

Tags: database, talend

I try to copy tables from one db to another, but when I try to copy a table which contains more then 10k rows it blocks. So I divided job into 2 jobs. One copy data before a certain date and another after this date. In this way I'm able to copy all, but I don't think it is the optimal way. Could you suggest me something?

Comment: why dont you use `expdp/impdp` export/Import data pump ?

Comment: i am not clear after reading this question as to what your DB's are..not sure if they are oracle, or others, what does blocks mean...talend job fails or any other thing...nothing is mentioned about your talend job - what components you are using, how you have designed the job....this seems to be very incomplete question...

Comment: it's oracle db. i use toracleInput, tmap, toracleOutput. "Blocks" means that nothing happens (copy nothing)

Answer (score 1):

The Document For `Oracle` Batabase which i have made long before may help you :

Exporting data :

Step 1 : Create a directory object it can access. The directory object is only a pointer to a physical directory, creating it does not actually create the physical directory on the file system of the database server.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY TEST_DIR AS '/U01/APP/ORACLE/ORADATA/ ';
GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIRECTORY TEST_DIR TO SCHEMA_NAME
```

Note : Create Directory Object using SYSDBA.

Step 2 :

```
expdp  SCHEMA_NAME/PASSWORD@SID TABLES=Table_Name CONTENT=DATA_ONLY 
VERSION=11.2  DIRECTORY=TEST_DIR  DUMPFILE=NAGENDRA.DMP LOGFILE=NAGENDRA_LOG.LOG
```

Note: You can skip `version` parameter if importing and exporting on same version.And if you want to cpoy entire table with table creation then remove `content` parameter.

Importing Data  :

Step 1 : Create a directory object it can access. The directory object is only a pointer to a physical directory, creating it does not actually create the physical directory on the file system of the database server.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY TEST_DIR AS '/U01/APP/ORACLE/ORADATA/ ';
GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIRECTORY TEST_DIR TO SCHEMA_NAME
```

Note : Create Directory Object using SYSDBA.

Step 2 : Copy dump file to directory using FTP. (If dump present on different server)
Note : Use Binary Transfer Mode of FTP else file may get corrupted.

Step 3 : Grant Permission to Schema as well as dump file.

```
GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE TO SCHEMA_NAME ;
```

Note : Using SYSDBA.

```
CHMOD 777 DUMP_FILE_NAME
```

Step 4 :  Use Import Command (IMPDP)

```
impdp SCHEMA_NAME/PASSWORD@SID DIRECTORY=TEST_DIR DUMPFILE=NAGENDRA.DMP
 LOGFILE=IMP_NAGENDRA_LOG.LOG FULL=Y  ;
```